# Exit to a different Activity when game loop ends?

Tags: android

I want my game to exit and go to a separate `Activity` when the user collides. For example, I want it to go back to my main menu. I've tried adding a `Button`, new intent method etc and these don't work. I can't find the answer anywhere and i'm not knowledgeable enough to do this as I'm learning. I've trawled the internet but nothing has really helped. Any advice would be awesome. My idea was to change the newgame() method to exit the game?

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Threading threading;
private BackgroundImage bg;
public static final int WIDTH = 856;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
public static final int MovementSpeed = -8;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<BorderTop> borderTop;
private ArrayList<BorderBottom> borderBottom;
private ArrayList<Smokepuff> smoke;
private ArrayList<Missile> missiles;
private int MaximumBorderHeight;
private int MinimumBorderHeight;
private boolean topDown = true;
private boolean botDown = true;
private int progressDifficulty = 20;
private Random rand = new Random();
private boolean newGameCreated;
private long smokeStartTime;
private long missileStartTime;



public GamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);


    setFocusable(true);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    bg = new BackgroundImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grassbg1));
    player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smallcatfinal), 40, 44, 1);
    borderTop = new ArrayList<BorderTop>();
    borderBottom = new ArrayList<BorderBottom>();
    smoke = new ArrayList<Smokepuff>();
    missiles = new ArrayList<Missile>();
    smokeStartTime=  System.nanoTime();
    missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();

    threading = new Threading(getHolder(), this);
    threading.setRunning(true);
    threading.start();



}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    boolean retry = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while (retry && counter < 1000) {
        counter++;
        try {
            threading.setRunning(false);
            threading.join();
            retry = false;
            threading = null;


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (!player.getPlaying()) {
            player.setPlaying(true);
            player.setUp(true);
        }else{
            player.setUp(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        player.setUp(false);
        return true;
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void update() {
    if (player.getPlaying()) {
        bg.update();
        player.update();


        MaximumBorderHeight = 30 + player.getScore() / progressDifficulty;

        if (MaximumBorderHeight > HEIGHT / 4) MaximumBorderHeight = HEIGHT / 4;
        MinimumBorderHeight = 5 + player.getScore() / progressDifficulty;


        //check bottom border collision
        for (int i = 0; i < borderBottom.size(); i++) {
            if (collision(borderBottom.get(i), player))
                player.setPlaying(false);

        }

        //check top border collision
        for (int i = 0; i < borderTop.size(); i++) {
            if (collision(borderTop.get(i), player))
                player.setPlaying(false);

        }

        this.updateTop();
        this.updateBottom();

        long missileElapsed = (System.nanoTime() - missileStartTime) / 1000000;
        if (missileElapsed > (2000 - player.getScore() / 4)) {


            //first missile always goes down the middle
            if (missiles.size() == 0) {
                missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.
                        missile), WIDTH + 10, HEIGHT / 2, 45, 15, player.getScore(), 13));
            } else {

                missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile),
                        WIDTH + 10, (int) (rand.nextDouble() * (HEIGHT - (MaximumBorderHeight * 2)) + MaximumBorderHeight), 45, 15, player.getScore(), 13));
            }

            //reset timer
            missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        //loop through every missile and check collision and remove
        for (int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++) {
            //update missile
            missiles.get(i).update();

            if (collision(missiles.get(i), player)) {
                missiles.remove(i);
                player.setPlaying(false);
                break;
            }
            //remove missile if it is way off the screen
            if (missiles.get(i).getX() < -100) {
                missiles.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }


        long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - smokeStartTime) / 1000000;
        if (elapsed > 120) {
            smoke.add(new Smokepuff(player.getX(), player.getY() + 10));
            smokeStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < smoke.size(); i++) {
            smoke.get(i).update();
            if (smoke.get(i).getX() < -10) {
                smoke.remove(i);
            }
        }
    } else {


        newGameCreated = false;
        if (!newGameCreated) {
            newGame();
        }
    }

    public boolean collision (GameObject a, GameObject b)
    {
        if (Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(), b.getRectangle())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    final float ScaleX = (float) getWidth() / WIDTH*1.f;
    final float ScaleY = (float) getHeight() / HEIGHT*1.f;
    if (canvas != null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(ScaleX, ScaleY);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        player.draw(canvas);
        for(Smokepuff sp: smoke)
        {
            sp.draw(canvas);
        }
        //draw missiles
        for(Missile m: missiles)
        {
            m.draw(canvas);
        }

        for(BorderTop bt: borderTop)
        {
            bt.draw(canvas);
        }
        for(BorderBottom bb: borderBottom)
        {
            bb.draw(canvas);
        }

        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}


public void updateBottom() {

  if (player.getScore() % 40 == 0) {
        borderBottom.add(new BorderBottom(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick),
             borderBottom.get(borderBottom.size() - 1).getX() + 20, (int) ((rand.nextDouble()
               * MaximumBorderHeight) + (HEIGHT - MaximumBorderHeight))));
   }

    //update bottom border
    for (int i = 0; i < borderBottom.size(); i++) {
        borderBottom.get(i).update();

        //if border is moving off screen, remove it and add a corresponding new one
        if (borderBottom.get(i).getX() < -20) {
            borderBottom.remove(i);


            //determine if border will be moving up or down
            if (borderBottom.get(borderBottom.size() - 1).getY() <= HEIGHT - MaximumBorderHeight) {
                botDown = true;
            }
            if (borderBottom.get(borderBottom.size() - 1).getY() >= HEIGHT - MinimumBorderHeight) {
                botDown = false;
            }

            if (botDown) {
                borderBottom.add(new BorderBottom(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick
                ), borderBottom.get(borderBottom.size() - 1).getX() + 20, borderBottom.get(borderBottom.size() - 1
                ).getY() + 1));
            } else {
                borderBottom.add(new BorderBottom(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
                ), borderBottom.get(borderBottom.size() - 1).getX() + 20, borderBottom.get(borderBottom.size() - 1
                ).getY() - 1));
            }


        }
    }
}


    public void updateTop()
    {
       if (player.getScore() % 50 == 0) {
          borderTop.add(new BorderTop(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick), borderTop.get(borderTop.size() - 1).getX() + 20, 0, (int) ((rand.nextDouble() * (MaximumBorderHeight)) + 1)));
       }
        for (int i = 0; i < borderTop.size(); i++) {
            borderTop.get(i).update();
            if (borderTop.get(i).getX() < -20) {
                borderTop.remove(i);


                if (borderTop.get(borderTop.size() - 1).getHeight() >= MaximumBorderHeight) {
                    topDown = false;
                }
                if (borderTop.get(borderTop.size() - 1).getHeight() <= MinimumBorderHeight) {
                    topDown = true;

                }
                if (topDown) {
                    borderTop.add(new BorderTop(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick), borderTop.get(borderTop.size() - 1).getX() + 20, 0, borderTop.get(borderTop.size() - 1).getHeight() + 1));
                } else {
                    borderTop.add(new BorderTop(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick), borderTop.get(borderTop.size() - 1).getX() + 20, 0, borderTop.get(borderTop.size() - 1).getHeight() - 1));
                }
            }
        }


    }
public void newGame() {

    borderBottom.clear();
     borderTop.clear();
     missiles.clear();
    smoke.clear();


      MinimumBorderHeight = 5;
     MaximumBorderHeight = 30;

     player.resetDY();
    player.resetScore();
    player.setY(HEIGHT/2);

    //create initial borders

    //initial top border
     for(int i = 0; i*20<WIDTH+40;i++)
    {
   // first top border create
    if(i==0)
      {borderTop.add(new BorderTop(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick
         ),i*20,0, 10));
     }
       else
       {
         borderTop.add(new BorderTop(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick
         ),i*20,0, borderTop.get(i-1).getHeight()+1));
      }
     }
      //initial bottom border
      for(int i = 0; i*20<WIDTH+40; i++)
       {
          //first border ever created
        if(i==0)
        {
          borderBottom.add(new BorderBottom(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick)
     ,i*20,HEIGHT - MinimumBorderHeight));
      }
    //adding borders until the initial screen is filed
      else
      {
          borderBottom.add(new BorderBottom(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick),
     i * 20, borderBottom.get(i - 1).getY() - 1));
      }
     }

    newGameCreated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error logs and code of when you use new intent to start the activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "a separate activity" ?